# Execução de PHP via Ajax jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou colocando algumas instruções dentro de um mesmo arquivo PHP que são executadas conforme o valor da variável `send` recebida, pelo menos era o que eu pensei. Neste código tem duas destas instruções, uma que recebe `send == 'buUserBloqueia'` e outra que recebe `send == 'cCadSend'` mas assim que a primeira recebe o comando, executa a instrução e não finaliza executando também as próximas que tem outro valor de `send`.

Código

```
// Função serve para bloquear o usuário do sistema
if((isset($_POST['send']) == "buUserBloqueia") && (isset($_POST['id']) != "")){

// Esta função bloqueia um usuário

exit();
}

// Função serve para cadastrar o usuário no sistema
if ((isset($_POST['send']) == "cCadSend")){

// Esta função cria um usuário

exit();
}
```

Porque será que ao submeter o Ajax com um valor de `send` especifico e após verificar o valor do `send` no PHP, o script continua executando todas as instruções abaixo dele?

Comment: Problema de atenção no código reaproveitado em que dentro da instrução estava repetindo um insert. Serviu para eu aprender que isset retorna true ou false. Abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) do PHP retorna `true` ou `false`.

Isto quer dizer que esta comparação `isset($_POST['send']) == "buUserBloqueia"` é sempre `false` pois `isset($_POST['send'])` não vai dar o valor do `$_POST['send']` mas sim `true` ou `false`.

No fundo seria o mesmo que comparar `if (true == "buUserBloqueia")`.
Sugiro que re-desenhe o seu código um pouco e fazer algo como:

```
if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] == "buUserBloqueia") && (isset($_POST['id']) != "")){
```

Ou colocar um `if` que faz exit mais cedo, antes do código que tem:

```
if(!isset($_POST['send'])) exit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que você queira literalmente criar um roteador HTTP, essa não é a melhor forma de se fazer. Além de não ser bom para a qualidade do código, não é possível testar e acaba com a sanidade dos programadores.

Sugiro que você dê uma olhada em componentes/bibliotecas prontos para fazer esse trabalho por você, como por exemplo o [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) que é um mini-framework muito fácil de utilizar. OInclusive ele já tralida com questões de segurança por você, permitindo que trabalhar com URLs Amigáveis de forma fácil.

Veja um exemplo de como ficaria essas suas duas ações com esse *framework*:

```
 require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

 $app = new Silex\Application(); 

 $app->post('/usuario/criar', function(){ 
    //aqui cria um usuário e retorna uma resposta 
 }); 

 $app->post('/usuario/bloquear', function(){ 
    //aqui bloqueia um usuário e retorna uma resposta 
 }); 

 $app->run();
```

Eu tenho [um repositório](https://github.com/fabioelizandro/lojagrafos) com uma aplicação que usa esse mini-framework que eu fiz para um trabalho de faculdade. De repente pode ajudar alguém.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer a verificação de um conjunto de ações eu prefiro utilizar o switch, acho que fica mais fácil de compreender e de modificar as instruções...

```
switch ($_POST['send']) {

    case 'buUserBloqueia':
        // Esta função bloqueia um usuário
        exit();
    break;

    case 'cCadSend':
        // Esta função cria um usuário
        exit();
    break;

}
```